# Properties of outer product of two unit vectors? Why is there only one non-zero eigenvalue for such a matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors, tensor-products, outer-product

Let $x,y$ be two unit vectors.

$A=xy^T$ be the outer product.

The eigenvalues of A are seen to be $[0, 0, 0,...0, k]$. Why is that?

What are the properties of the outer product of two unit vectors?

Why is there only one non-zero eigenvalue for such a matrix?

Comment: Multiply $Ae = \lambda e$ on the left by $y^T$ and consider associativity of the products involved.

Comment: Every column of $A$ is a multiple of $x$, hence it has rank 1.

Comment: @amd Thanks. That is the answer I was looking for. I can't see why you did not write it as an answer.

Comment: Seemed too short to me to be an answer (and will likely get flagged as too short by overzealous reviewers), but I’m happy to make it so.

Comment: @amd Simple answer is the best answer, right?

Comment: @Paul $(y^Tx)(y^Te)=\lambda (y^Te) \implies \lambda = y^Tx$ ? Is that what you are saying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every column of $A$ is a multiple of $x$ and every row is a multiple of $y$. $x$ and $y$ are both nonzero, hence $A$ has rank 1. Moreover, $k=y^Tx$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an elementary proof. If $A = xy^T$ and $v$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with corresponding eigenvalue $\lambda$, then $\lambda v = Av = (xy^T)v = x(y^T v)$. Note that $y^T v$ is a scalar. Assume $\lambda \ne 0$, and divide through by $\lambda$ to get $v = x(y^T v / \lambda)$. Put $c = y^Tv/\lambda$. We have $Av = A(cx) = xy^T cx = (y^Tx)cx = (y^T x)v$, so $\lambda = y^Tx$.

One way to show that the algebraic multiplicity of the eigenvalue $y^Tx$ is $1$ is to take the trace: $tr(A) = tr(xy^T) = tr(y^T x) = y^Tx$. The trace is the sum of eigenvalues, so if $y^Tx \ne 0$ then the multiplicity of $y^Tx$ must be $1$.

Comment: $xy^Tcx=(y^Tx)cx$, how ?

Comment: Because $c$ and $y^Tx$ are scalars, so we can move them around however we like. Write $d = y^Tx$, then $xy^Tcx = c(xy^Tx) = c x d = dcx$.

Comment: In case this seems strange, understand that the expression $y^Tx$ is playing two very distinct roles: First, a $1 \times 1$ matrix, and second, a scalar. It wouldn't make sense to write $(y^Tx)x$ if $y^T x$ were a $1 \times 1$ matrix, because the dimensions are incompatible with the column matrix $x$. Unfortunately, this cavalier notation is standard.

Comment: Yes, I understood. And thank you.